# What does "right" mean in "when the wind was right"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

I found the following sentence in a paragraph:

“Sometimes, when the wind was right, you could hear the surf all over the town.”

I’ve never seen “right wind” in the context and it’s some sort of a wierd phrase to me, and since the text I’m working on to translate is full of idioms and slangs, so I was wondeing if someone can assure me that does “right” here as an adjective for “wind” has any idiomatic or hidden meaning?

All answers and comments are appreciated.

Comment: You have two options, it can be the opposite of _left_ or the opposite of _wrong_. The former doesn't seem to make much sense, but does the latter cause any confusion? If so, please specify that in your question.

Comment: You are quite right. My question is in fact a double-check to make sure if there is any hidden meaning here for the word “right” as an adjective for the wind. I’ve edited the q. Thanks any way :)

Comment: it's short for "blowing in the right (a particular one) direction"

Answer (score 1):

In that context "right" means in such a direction and of such a strength that the sound of the waves sometimes carried all over town.

There is something of a tautology here because the sentence is literally saying that when the wind is such that the sound of waves could sometimes be heard all over town, then the sound of waves could sometimes be heard all over town. Nevertheless it is quite idiomatic.

Another way of putting it would be to say:"Depending on the wind, you could sometimes hear..."

Answer (score 0):

[American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/right) gives us

> **4** Most favorable, desirable, or convenient: *the right time to act.*

The part that's relevant here is "most favorable."

If you want to use this meaning of "right" in your speech and writing, it is often clearer to say "just right" instead.